# NET 6 Minimal API -'No public static bool Request.TryParse(string, out Request) method found for request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Using .NET 6 I have the following Minimal API in Program.cs:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
builder.Services.AddRouting();

await using WebApplication application = builder.Build();

application.UseRouting();

application.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () => { });

application.MapGet("countries", async ([FromQuery]Request request, IMediator mediator) => {
  Payload<List<Response>> payload = await mediator.Send(request);
  return Results.Ok(payload);
});

await application.RunAsync();
```

Where `Request` is:

```
public class Request { 
  public List<Int32> Ids { get; set; } = new List<Int32>();
}
```

When I run the application I get the error on "countries" endpoint:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll: 'No public static bool Request.TryParse(string, out Request) method found for request.'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.BindParameterFromValue(ParameterInfo parameter, Expression valueExpression, FactoryContext factoryContext, String source)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.CreateArgument(ParameterInfo parameter, FactoryContext factoryContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.CreateArguments(ParameterInfo[] parameters, FactoryContext factoryContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.CreateTargetableRequestDelegate(MethodInfo methodInfo, Expression targetExpression, FactoryContext factoryContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Create(Delegate handler, RequestDelegateFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.Map(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, RoutePattern pattern, Delegate handler, Boolean disableInferBodyFromParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapMethods(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern, IEnumerable`1 httpMethods, Delegate handler)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGet(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern, Delegate handler)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error basically means that ASP.NET Core doesn't know how to bind your querystring to the `Request` you have defined.

Is `Request` a custom type? If so, you need to add a static `TryParse` method which takes a string (the query string), and out parameter of the `Request` object which you will need to initialize by parsing the query string.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding)

Comment: Yes, `Request` is a class with one property of type `List<Int32>`. Shouldn't ASP.NET Core perform the binding automatically?

Comment: @MiguelMoura in case of Minimal APIs - no. AFAIK automatically complex types are bound only for json bodies. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-precedence)

Answer (score 5):

As of dotnet 7, you can use the `[AsParameters]` attribute as follows:

```
application.MapGet("countries", async ([AsParameters] Request request, IMediator mediator) => {
  Payload<List<Response>> payload = await mediator.Send(request);
  return Results.Ok(payload);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you remove the `[FromQuery]` attribute and add a `BindAsync` method to the Request class as follows:

```
public class Request
{
    public List<Int32> Ids { get; set; } = new List<Int32>();

    public static ValueTask<Request> BindAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string[] queries = context.Request.Query[nameof(Ids)];
        var result = new Request
        {
            Ids = queries.Select(int.Parse).ToList()
        };

        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```